# Android: get listview onClick to new intent

Tags: android, listview

i hava got the code below. i want to start an activity when i click on a single item on the list. however when i do nothing happens. I alsow want every item to refer to the same intent calld "com.whiskey.app.view" and send a id variable that was given by the sql query. I browsed trough the code several times but i cant seem t get it to work.

```
  public class MainScreen extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{

  public ListView whiskeylist;
  public String[] DataArryWhiskey; 

  ....

   @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Start db view of whiskey

    DBConfig whiskeyrows = new DBConfig(this);


    whiskeyrows.open();
        DataArryWhiskey = whiskeyrows.getDataInArray();
    whiskeyrows.close(); 


    whiskeylist = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listofWhiskey);
    whiskeylist.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , DataArryWhiskey));


    // End db view of whiskey

}// end onCreate


// catch itemclick event from the main list.
public void onItemClick(AdapterView av, View v, int position, long l) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    String[] listitem_data = DataArryWhiskey[position].split(","); // break passed sting into a array comma seperated

    Bundle passingitems = new Bundle();
    passingitems.putString("whiskey_id", listitem_data[0]);

    Intent currentintent = new Intent("com.wiskey.app.view");
    currentintent.putExtras(passingitems);

    startActivity(currentintent);

}
```

Comment: Is your onItemClick called at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the above answers work, I think that the problem in your current implementation is that you don't call:

```
whiskeylist.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

I think this should do the work!

Answer (score 2):

If your `activity` only cotains this `ListView`, you should use a `ListActivity`.
These are made specifically for activities that only contain lists.

One of the methods for `ListActivities` is `onListItemClick`. That one is specifically for clicking on items in lists, as the name says. 
The reason your code doesn't work is because `onItemClick` isn't generally used for clicking in `Lists`, but for clicking other objects in `Activities`.

Try changing your code based on the samples here: [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)

Answer (score 2):

Derive your class from `ListActivity` and remove the `implements OnItemClickListener`

Put below code in `onCreate`

```
setListAdapter(whiskeylist);
```

And then have this as your `onItemClick`

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

  String[] listitem_data = DataArryWhiskey[position].split(","); // break passed sting into a array comma seperated

  ...your code....
  startActivity(currentintent);
}
```

Also refer to:

[ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)
[ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have not added listener for click actions, try adding:

```
whiskeylist.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

at the end of onCreate

You might also write anonymous OnItemClickListener as in here:
    http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html